# Async Server handling many clients and messages in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, client

I would like to create a server which handles multiple clients and handles them all in an async fashion.

Based on the link below I created my code :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx

After some inspection of the MSDN Code realized that the manual event code does blocking.

My query about the solution is if the server is designed to accept many connections from many clients then won't making the thread wait until the connectcallback tells it that it is finished cause any potential connecting clients connecting at the time of the waiting timeout or drop?

Comment: A picture of an error is about the most useless thing you can provide.  Surround your errored code with `try{ /*code*/}catch(Exception ex){ var weNeedThis = ex.ToString(); }`  Calling ToString on the exception gets the error message, inner exception details and the stack trace.  Do that, [edit] and add the exception details where you say you'll add an image.

Comment: @ will, you do realize that Console.WriteLine(); calls the ToString Method and that the picture is exactly what you're asking for... right?

Comment: Nope, didn't look at it.  Of course, if I wanted to do a search based on text in the exception I would have to transcribe the image.  Not very friendly.  You could have simply copied the console output into your question in this case, which puzzles me.

Comment: @Will, For reference, I didn't do it because I couldn't simply copy the console output, otherwise I would have, also the exception is in the second link and the picture shows where the exception is thrown in my code; however, I will still take the liberty to add it to the question as it may be unreasonable to ask you to look at third party sites for additional information about the question

Comment: Believe me, it helps increase the chances that people will give you an answer :)